# Background colour for cells with padding

Tags: tables, color, margins, border

I have a pretty complex table where I had to add some borders and some padding.
Now I want to colour these "special" cells with a background. But the colour is not expanding to the padding. Are there any way to extend it? this is my MWE code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}

     a & b & & d \\
       &   & &   \\ \cline{1-2}
     \multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{3em}}c@{\hspace{1em}}}{\cellcolor{red!50} E } 
       & 
     \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\hspace{3em}}|}{\cellcolor{red!50}  F  } 
       &   &  h
     \\[15pt] \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and this his how it appears:

[image]

the yellow highlighted parts in the next image should get coloured too. Further I discovered, that the border on the top is missing. Why? How can I get her back?

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\cellcolor` has `overhang` (padding) arguments, see `colortbl` documentation please (`colortbl` is loaded by `xcolor` when `table` option is used)

Comment: for `\cline` see the `colortbl` documentation, it is explicitly not supported. (You could use `\hhline` from the hhline package instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to obtain it. Note `hhline` is required with coloured cells.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     a & b & & d \\
       & & & \\ \hhline{--~~}
     \multicolumn{1}{| @{\color{red!50}\vrule width 3em}c@{\color{red!50}\vrule width 1em}}{\cellcolor{red!50} E }
       &
     \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\color{red!50}\vrule width 3em}|}{\cellcolor{red!50} F }
       & & h
     \\[15pt] \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     a & b & & d \\
       & & & \\ \hhline{--~~}%
     \multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{3em}}>{\columncolor{red!50}[3em][1em]}c@{\hspace{1em}}}{ E }
       &
     \multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\columncolor{red!50}[0.4pt][3em]}c@{\hspace{3em}}|}{ F }
       & & h
     \\[15pt] \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great. Pretty close on my code. I Like this. (Please not that the code is not completely marked/ indended as code)

Answer (score 6):

In general I do such things with tikz and \tikzmark. The horizontal coordinates are normally quite easy to get. The vertical need sometimes some calculation or more \tikzmarks. The neat thing is that you can draw the background before the tabular and so it is really always in the background.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[red!50] ([yshift=-\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+15pt]pic cs:A) 
               rectangle ([yshift=\ht\strutbox]pic cs:B);

\begin{tabular}{cccc}

     a & b & & d \\
       &   & &   \\ \cline{1-2}
     \multicolumn{1}{|@{\tikzmark{A}\hspace{3em}}c@{\hspace{1em}}}{ E }
       &
     \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\hspace{3em}\tikzmark{B}}|}{  F  }
       &   &  h
     \\[15pt] \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks really nice, but for some reason it adds a blank page (not with the MWE, but within my doc) somehow caused by the two lines right after `\begin{document}`, but I will try to fix it

Comment: The tikz code is a small zero sized box but nevertheless a box. So put it in a place where such a box doesn't do harm eg after a word.

Comment: What a clever solution! Thanks @UlrikeFischer for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

By using the environment `{NiceTabular}` instead of the environment `{tabular}` and the key `colortbl-like` (the syntax of `colortbl` will be using even though `colortbl` itself won't be used), we have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[colortbl-like]
     a & b & & d \\
       &   & &   \\ \cline{1-2}
     \multicolumn{1}{|@{\hspace{3em}}c@{\hspace{1em}}}{\cellcolor{red!50} E } 
       & 
     \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\hspace{3em}}|}{\cellcolor{red!50}  F  } 
       &   &  h
     \\[15pt] \cline{1-2}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Ouput of the above code]