# tcolorbox with text near title in the first line

Tags: tcolorbox

My goal is it to recreate the following box:
[image]
All I can achieve is the following box, but I would like to have the text in the upper part in the same line as the title, as in the original image, I try to recreate.
[image]
Right now this is my approach using the tcolorbox package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tasks}

\definecolor{textnewGreen}{HTML}{66AE3E}
\definecolor{bgnewGreen}{HTML}{EBF4DE}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{gruenebox}[1]{
enhanced,
skin=bicolor,
arc=0pt,
coltitle=white,
colframe=textnewGreen,
colback=bgnewGreen,
colbacklower=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
boxed title style={colback=textnewGreen,frame code={
            \path[fill=textnewGreen](frame.north west)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east)
            -- (frame.south west)
            -- (frame.north west)
              [sharp corners]-- cycle;
            }
          },
          fonttitle=\bfseries,
          title={#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gruenebox}{Beispiel 1}
 Schätze und begründe deine Schätzung.
 \begin{tasks}
 \task Wie hoch ist eine Getränkedose?
 \task  Wie viel wiegt eine volle Kiste mit 12 1-l Wasserflaschen?
 \end{tasks}
 \tcblower
 \paragraph{Lösung}
 \begin{tasks}
 \task Eine Getränkedose ist ungefähr genauso hoch wie eine Handlänge. Eine Hand ist etwa 10 cm bis 20 cm lang.
 \task Liter Wasser wiegt etwa 1 kg. 12 Liter wiegen also 12 kg. Dazu kommen noch das Gewicht der Kiste und das Gewicht der Flaschen. Also wiegt die Kiste zwischen 13 und 15 kg für Plastikflaschen, bei Glas noch mehr.   
 \end{tasks}
\end{gruenebox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the title is first `detach`ed, then (re)inserted to the upper part in `before upper*=<x- and y- offset>\titlebox{\tcbtitletext}`, where `\titlebox` is a costumed `\tcbox`.

Explanations for the magic numbers

- `baseline=3pt`: this could be replaced with some multiples of `\baselineskip - \f@size pt`
- two `.1pt` used in `<x- and y- offset>`: to make the title box and the outer tcolorbox not just touch, but overlap a bit. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557897) for more detailed info.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tasks}

\definecolor{textnewGreen}{HTML}{66AE3E}
\definecolor{bgnewGreen}{HTML}{EBF4DE}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\titlebox}{
  enhanced,
  colupper=white,
  colback=textnewGreen,
  fontupper=\bfseries,
  size=small,
  baseline=3pt,
  nobeforeafter,
  frame code={
    \path[fill=textnewGreen] (frame.north west)
    -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
    -- (frame.south east)
    -- (frame.south west)
    -- (frame.north west)
      [sharp corners]-- cycle;
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{gruenebox}[1]{
  enhanced,
  skin=bicolor,
  arc=0pt,
  coltitle=white,
  colframe=textnewGreen,
  colback=bgnewGreen,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  detach title,
  title={#1},
  before upper*={%
    \vskip-\dimexpr\kvtcb@boxsep+\kvtcb@top+.1pt
    \hspace*{-\dimexpr\kvtcb@boxsep+\kvtcb@leftupper+.1pt}%
    \expandafter\titlebox\expandafter{\tcbtitletext} %
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gruenebox}{Beispiel 1}
 Schätze und begründe deine Schätzung.
 \begin{tasks}
 \task Wie hoch ist eine Getränkedose?
 \task  Wie viel wiegt eine volle Kiste mit 12 1-l Wasserflaschen?
 \end{tasks}
 \tcblower
 \paragraph{Lösung}
 \begin{tasks}
 \task Eine Getränkedose ist ungefähr genauso hoch wie eine Handlänge. Eine Hand ist etwa 10 cm bis 20 cm lang.
 \task Liter Wasser wiegt etwa 1 kg. 12 Liter wiegen also 12 kg. Dazu kommen noch das Gewicht der Kiste und das Gewicht der Flaschen. Also wiegt die Kiste zwischen 13 und 15 kg für Plastikflaschen, bei Glas noch mehr.   
 \end{tasks}
\end{gruenebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]