# Annoying color lines in table

Tags: tables, color

I'm writing a manual, and a table I need to include looks awful when compiling. This is my code, loading `xcolor` in the preamble:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$}
    \label{tabF}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cccccccccc|}
            \cline{3-12}
             &  & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$)}} \\ \cline{3-12} 
             &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}9} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}10 \\ \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}161,4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}199,5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}215,7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}224,6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}230,2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}234} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}236,8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}238,9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}240,5} & 241,9 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18,51} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,00} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,16} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,30} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,33} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,35} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,37} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{19,38} & 19,40 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}10,13} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}9,552} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}9,277} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}9,117} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}9,013} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}8,941} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}8,887} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}8,845} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}8,812} & 8,786 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}4 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7,709} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,944} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,591} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,388} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,256} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,163} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,094} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6,041} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,999} & 5,964 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}5 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}6,608} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,786} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,409} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,192} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,050} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,950} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,876} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,818} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,772} & 4,735 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}6 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,987} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,143} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,757} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,534} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,387} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,284} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,207} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,147} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,099} & 4,060 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}7 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,591} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,737} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,347} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,120} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,972} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,866} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,787} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,726} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,677} & 3,637 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}8 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5,318} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,459} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,066} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,838} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,687} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,581} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,500} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,438} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,388} & 3,347 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}9 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}5,117} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}4,256} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,863} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,633} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,482} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,374} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,293} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,230} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}3,179} & 3,137 \\ \cline{2-12} 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{4cm}{\centering {\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Grados de libertad del denominador ($s_2$)}}}}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}10 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,965} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4,103} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,708} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,478} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,326} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,217} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,135} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,072} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3,020} & 2,978 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The product end up looking like this:
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the white lines in the first column without changing too much code (like loading more packages who mess with another tables)? The manual is huge, and so will be the time spent in inspecting on the other tables if I change too much code in the preamble.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use hhline to draw the rules, of the right colour but why have horizontal rules at all, they add nothing useful to the coloured rows. In general it helps if you provide a full test file not just a fragment

Comment: I've tried eliminating the horizontal rules (you were right, his absence was not noticed), but the annoying white lines still are there. Same with ```hhline```

Comment: The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that problem: see this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380946/remove-thin-white-line-in-dark-colored-cells)

Answer (score 5):

Getting rid of almost all vertical and horizontal black lines brings about the desired relief. The horizontal lines are causing the problem you encountered, and the vertical lines won't be missed.

That said, you may want to reconsider how useful the table's color scheme really is -- or whether "simple" table might actually be better. See the following two tables for a stark comparison. The simple table clearly isn't as "showy"; however, might it actually "work" better for your readers?

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifpdftex
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage{lmodern}
    \else
      \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \fi
    
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,multirow,graphicx,icomma}
    %some useful shortcuts:
    \newcommand\colorA{\cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}}
    \newcommand\colorB{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF}}
    \newcommand\colorC{\cellcolor[HTML]{709DE6}}
    \newcommand\colorD{\cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}}
    \newcommand\rcolorE{\rowcolor[HTML]{709DE6}}
    
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$\strut}
    \label{tabF}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{12}{c} | }
    
    &  & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\colorD \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\boldmath Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$)}} \\  
    &  & \colorA 1 & \colorA 2 & \colorA 3 & \colorA 4 & \colorA 5 & \colorA 6 & \colorA 7 & \colorA 8 & \colorA 9 & \colorA 10 \\ %\hline
      \rcolorE  
      \colorD & \colorA 1 & \colorC 161,4 & \colorC 199,5 & \colorC 215,7 & \colorC 224,6 & \colorC 230,2 & \colorC 234 & \colorC 236,8 & \colorC 238,9 & \colorC 240,5 & 241,9 \\  
      \colorD & \colorA 2 & 18,51 & 19,00 & 19,16 & 19,25 & 19,30 & 19,33 & 19,35 & 19,37 & 19,38 & 19,40 \\    
      \rcolorE  
      \colorD & \colorA 3 & \colorC 10,13 & \colorC 9,552 & \colorC 9,277 & \colorC 9,117 & \colorC 9,013 & \colorC 8,941 & \colorC 8,887 & \colorC 8,845 & \colorC 8,812 & 8,786 \\  
      \colorD & \colorA 4 & 7,709 & 6,944 & 6,591 & 6,388 & 6,256 & 6,163 & 6,094 & 6,041 & 5,999 & 5,964 \\  
      \rcolorE  
      \colorD & \colorA 5 & \colorC 6,608 & \colorC 5,786 & \colorC 5,409 & \colorC 5,192 & \colorC 5,050 & \colorC 4,950 & \colorC 4,876 & \colorC 4,818 & \colorC 4,772 & 4,735 \\  
      \colorD & \colorA 6 & 5,987 & 5,143 & 4,757 & 4,534 & 4,387 & 4,284 & 4,207 & 4,147 & 4,099 & 4,060 \\  
      \rcolorE  
      \colorD & \colorA 7 & \colorC 5,591 & \colorC 4,737 & \colorC 4,347 & \colorC 4,120 & \colorC 3,972 & \colorC 3,866 & \colorC 3,787 & \colorC 3,726 & \colorC 3,677 & 3,637 \\  
      \colorD & \colorA 8 & 5,318 & 4,459 & 4,066 & 3,838 & 3,687 & 3,581 & 3,500 & 3,438 & 3,388 & 3,347 \\  
      \rcolorE  
      \colorD & \colorA 9 & \colorC 5,117 & \colorC 4,256 & \colorC 3,863 & \colorC 3,633 & \colorC 3,482 & \colorC 3,374 & \colorC 3,293 & \colorC 3,230 & \colorC 3,179 & 3,137 \\  
      \multirow{-10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{4cm}{\centering \colorD \textcolor{white}{\bfseries\boldmath Grados de libertad del denominador ($s_2$)}}}} & \colorA 10 & 4,965 & 4,103 & 3,708 & 3,478 & 3,326 & 3,217 & 3,135 & 3,072 & 3,020 & 2,978 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{5mm}
    \caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$\strut}
    \label{tabF_nocolors}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{12}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    &  & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$)} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){3-12} 
    &  &  1 &  2 &  3 &  4 &  5 &  6 &  7 &  8 &  9 &  10 \\ 
    \midrule
       &  1 &  161,4 &  199,5 &  215,7 &  224,6 &  230,2 &  234 &  236,8 &  238,9 &  240,5 & 241,9 \\  
       &  2 & 18,51 & 19,00 & 19,16 & 19,25 & 19,30 & 19,33 & 19,35 & 19,37 & 19,38 & 19,40 \\         
       &  3 &  10,13 &  9,552 &  9,277 &  9,117 &  9,013 &  8,941 &  8,887 &  8,845 &  8,812 & 8,786 \\  
       &  4 & 7,709 & 6,944 & 6,591 & 6,388 & 6,256 & 6,163 & 6,094 & 6,041 & 5,999 & 5,964 \\         
       &  5 &  6,608 &  5,786 &  5,409 &  5,192 &  5,050 &  4,950 &  4,876 &  4,818 &  4,772 & 4,735 \\
\addlinespace  
       &  6 & 5,987 & 5,143 & 4,757 & 4,534 & 4,387 & 4,284 & 4,207 & 4,147 & 4,099 & 4,060 \\       
       &  7 &  5,591 &  4,737 &  4,347 &  4,120 &  3,972 &  3,866 &  3,787 &  3,726 &  3,677 & 3,637 \\  
       &  8 & 5,318 & 4,459 & 4,066 & 3,838 & 3,687 & 3,581 & 3,500 & 3,438 & 3,388 & 3,347 \\      
       &  9 &  5,117 &  4,256 &  3,863 &  3,633 &  3,482 &  3,374 &  3,293 &  3,230 &  3,179 & 3,137 \\  
      \multirow{-10.5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{4cm}{\centering Grados de libertad del denominador ($s_2$)}}} & 10 & 4,965 & 4,103 & 3,708 & 3,478 & 3,326 & 3,217 & 3,135 & 3,072 & 3,020 & 2,978 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{5cm}{\centering #1}}}
\definecolor{myblue1}{HTML}{174EA6}
\definecolor{myblue2}{HTML}{3368BD}
\definecolor{myblue3}{HTML}{709DE6}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$}
\label{tabF}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec             = {*{12}{Q[c,m]}},
cell{1}{3}          = {c=10}{},
hline{1,2}          = {3-Z}{},
hline{3-Z}          = {2-Z}{},
vline{1,2}          = {3-Z}{},
vline{4-Y}          = {2-Z}{},
hline{3,Z}          = {},
vline{3,Z}          = {},
cell{3}{1}          = {r=10}{cmd=\mybox},
cell{1}{3-Z}        = {bg=myblue1,fg=white},
cell{3-Z}{1-2}      = {bg=myblue1,fg=white},
cell{2}{3-Z}        = {bg=myblue2},
cell{3-Z}{2}        = {bg=myblue2},
cell{odd[3-Z]}{3-Z} = {bg=myblue3},
}
                                              &    & Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$) &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
                                              &    & 1                                        & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 9     & 10    \\
{Grados de libertad del\\denominador ($s_2$)} & 1  & 161,4                                    & 199,5 & 215,7 & 224,6 & 230,2 & 234   & 236,8 & 238,9 & 240,5 & 241,9 \\
                                              & 2  & 18,51                                    & 19,00 & 19,16 & 19,25 & 19,30 & 19,33 & 19,35 & 19,37 & 19,38 & 19,40 \\
                                              & 3  & 10,13                                    & 9,552 & 9,277 & 9,117 & 9,013 & 8,941 & 8,887 & 8,845 & 8,812 & 8,786 \\
                                              & 4  & 7,709                                    & 6,944 & 6,591 & 6,388 & 6,256 & 6,163 & 6,094 & 6,041 & 5,999 & 5,964 \\
                                              & 5  & 6,608                                    & 5,786 & 5,409 & 5,192 & 5,050 & 4,950 & 4,876 & 4,818 & 4,772 & 4,735 \\
                                              & 6  & 5,987                                    & 5,143 & 4,757 & 4,534 & 4,387 & 4,284 & 4,207 & 4,147 & 4,099 & 4,060 \\
                                              & 7  & 5,591                                    & 4,737 & 4,347 & 4,120 & 3,972 & 3,866 & 3,787 & 3,726 & 3,677 & 3,637 \\
                                              & 8  & 5,318                                    & 4,459 & 4,066 & 3,838 & 3,687 & 3,581 & 3,500 & 3,438 & 3,388 & 3,347 \\
                                              & 9  & 5,117                                    & 4,256 & 3,863 & 3,633 & 3,482 & 3,374 & 3,293 & 3,230 & 3,179 & 3,137 \\
                                              & 10 & 4,965                                    & 4,103 & 3,708 & 3,478 & 3,326 & 3,217 & 3,135 & 3,072 & 3,020 & 2,978 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One more solution with use of the `tabularray` package (similar to nice @Clara answer (+1) but instead of the  `graphicx` is employed `makecell`. For numbers are used `S` column of `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\definecolor{DB}{HTML}{174EA6}
\definecolor{LB}{HTML}{3368BD}
\definecolor{MB}{HTML}{709DE6}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$}
\label{tabF}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\setlength\rotheadsize{9\baselineskip}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2}={3-Z}{solid}, hline{3-Z}={solid},
             vline{1,2}={3-Z}{solid}, vline{3-Z}={solid},
             colspec = {cc*{10}{X[c, si={table-format=3.3,
                                         table-auto-round,
                                         output-decimal-marker={,}}]}},
             colsep  = {3pt},
             cell{3-Z}{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=DB, fg=white, 
                             cmd=\rothead},
             cell{3-Z}{2} = {font=\bfseries, bg=LB,},
             cell{odd[3]}{3-Z} = {bg=MB},
             cell{1}{3-Z} = {font=\bfseries, bg=DB, fg=white},
             cell{2}{3-Z} = {font=\bfseries, bg=LB},
             row{1,2} = {guard}
             }
    &   & \SetCell[c=10]{c} Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$)
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10    \\
\SetCell[r=9]{m}   \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Grados de libertad del denominador ($s_1$)}
    & 1 & 161,4 & 199,5 & 215,7 & 224,6 & 230,2 & 
          234   & 236,8 & 238,9 & 240,5 & 241,9     \\
    & 2 & 18,51 & 19,00 & 19,16 & 19,25 & 19,30 & 
          19,33 & 19,35 & 19,37 & 19,38 & 19,40     \\
    & 3 & 10,13 & 9,552 & 9,277 & 9,117 & 9,013 & 
          8,941 & 8,887 & 8,845 & 8,812 & 8,786     \\
    & 4 & 7,709 & 6,944 & 6,591 & 6,388 & 6,256 &
          6,163 & 6,094 & 6,041 & 5,999 & 5,964     \\
    & 5 & 6,608 & 5,786 & 5,409 & 5,192 & 5,050 & 
          4,950 & 4,876 & 4,818 & 4,772 & 4,735     \\
    & 6 & 5,987 & 5,143 & 4,757 & 4,534 & 4,387 &
          4,284 & 4,207 & 4,147 & 4,099 & 4,060     \\
    & 7 & 5,591 & 4,737 & 4,347 & 4,120 & 3,972 & 
          3,866 & 3,787 & 3,726 & 3,677 & 3,637     \\
    & 8 & 5,318 & 4,459 & 4,066 & 3,838 & 3,687 &
          3,581 & 3,500 & 3,438 & 3,388 & 3,347     \\
    & 9 & 5,117 & 4,256 & 3,863 & 3,633 & 3,482 & 
          3,374 & 3,293 & 3,230 & 3,179 & 3,137     \\     
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with a perfect output (you won't see any thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Valores críticos de $F$ para una prueba con $\alpha = 0,05$}
\label{tabF}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=3.3,table-auto-round,output-decimal-marker={,}]}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,corners=NW]{c>{\bfseries}c*{10}{T}}
\CodeBefore
    \cellcolor[HTML]{174EA6}{1-,-1}
    \cellcolor[HTML]{3368BD}{2-,-2}
    \rowcolors[HTML]{3}{709DE6}{}[cols=3-*]
\Body
        &   & \Block{1-*}{\color{white}Grados de libertad del numerador ($s_1$)} \\
    \RowStyle[bold]{}
        &   & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10}    \\
    \Block{*-1}<\rotate\color{white}>{Grados de libertad\\ del denominador ($s_1$)}
        & 1 & 161,4 & 199,5 & 215,7 & 224,6 & 230,2 & 
              234   & 236,8 & 238,9 & 240,5 & 241,9     \\
        & 2 & 18,51 & 19,00 & 19,16 & 19,25 & 19,30 & 
              19,33 & 19,35 & 19,37 & 19,38 & 19,40     \\
        & 3 & 10,13 & 9,552 & 9,277 & 9,117 & 9,013 & 
              8,941 & 8,887 & 8,845 & 8,812 & 8,786     \\
        & 4 & 7,709 & 6,944 & 6,591 & 6,388 & 6,256 &
              6,163 & 6,094 & 6,041 & 5,999 & 5,964     \\
        & 5 & 6,608 & 5,786 & 5,409 & 5,192 & 5,050 & 
              4,950 & 4,876 & 4,818 & 4,772 & 4,735     \\
        & 6 & 5,987 & 5,143 & 4,757 & 4,534 & 4,387 &
              4,284 & 4,207 & 4,147 & 4,099 & 4,060     \\
        & 7 & 5,591 & 4,737 & 4,347 & 4,120 & 3,972 & 
              3,866 & 3,787 & 3,726 & 3,677 & 3,637     \\
        & 8 & 5,318 & 4,459 & 4,066 & 3,838 & 3,687 &
              3,581 & 3,500 & 3,438 & 3,388 & 3,347     \\
        & 9 & 5,117 & 4,256 & 3,863 & 3,633 & 3,482 & 
              3,374 & 3,293 & 3,230 & 3,179 & 3,137     \\     
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I have post this answer but I recommend the design of tables provided by `booktabs` (see Mico's answer).