# Remove white line in painted multirow tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment

I have a table where the first row contains a multirow cell. The multi-row should be coloured gray.

**Question 1**

Unfortunately, a thin white line appears between the multirows (see the picture at the end). Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
 \arrayrulecolor{black} %changes color of hline
 \hline
 \rowcolor{gray!50} & {Max Power} & {Typ. Range}\\
 \rowcolor{gray!50}\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Class}} & (mW)  &  (m) \\
 \hline
 \textbf{1} &  100 & 100\\
 \textbf{2} & 2.5 & 10\\
 \textbf{3} & 1 & 1\\
 \textbf{4} & 0.5 & 0.5\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Σύγκριση μεταξύ 2.4GHz και 5GHz}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

**Question2**

Furthermore, I would like to adjust the spacing indicated with the red arrow. I would like it to be smaller, so that the text is closer to the line above, just for this specific row.

[image]

Comment: Not related: In a environment `{table}`, you should use `\centering` and not `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` (for correct spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With column headers in `\thead` command defined in the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    %\arrayrulecolor{black} %changes color of hline
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\bfseries}c | c | c | }
    \hline
 \rowcolor{gray!50} 
    & \thead{Max Power\\ (mW)} & \thead{Typ. Range\\ (m)}\\
    \hline
1 &  100 & 100  \\
2 & 2.5  & 10   \\
3 & 1    & 1    \\
4 & 0.5  & 0.5  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Text in Greek language \SI{2.4}{GHz} ... \SI{5}{GHz}.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* please, always provide an MWE, is the smallest complete document that reproduces the problem. It should contain all necessary packages and definitions required to run the example, but nothing more than that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will do from now on.

Answer (score 5):

The package `nicematrix` has tools to deal with that problem. With the following code, the thin white lines won't appear (they appear in some PDF viewers with the tools of `colortbl`, which is loaded by the option `table` of `xcolor`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}ccc}[vlines]
\CodeBefore 
   \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
   \rowcolor{gray!50}{1,2} 
\Body
   \hline
   \Block{2-1}{Class} & Max Power & Typ. Range\\[-3mm]
                      & (mW)      &  (m) \\
   \hline
   1 &  100 & 100\\
   2 & 2.5 & 10\\
   3 & 1 & 1\\
   4 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
   \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Very useful answer, however I preferred to use the tabular environment. This works perfectly though as well.

Comment: With `{tabular}` as in the answer of Bernard, you will still have problems in some PDF viewers: for instance, with Adobe Reader DC, at some levels of zoom, the vertical rule on the left will seem to disappear. With `nicematrix`, you won't have that effect because `nicematrix`constructs all the colored rectangles *before* the construction of the rules (this is not the case with `colortbl`). For an example, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542455/coloring-cells-in-a-table-redux-vertical-and-horizontal-bars-hidden-in-most-vie).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `makecell` and its eponymous command. This way, you won't need `\multirow`  and the vertical spacing in the column heads will be shorter.
(*Note*: I had to translate the caption text because I had troubles with my editor)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, float, makecell}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
 \arrayrulecolor{black} %changes color of hline
 \hline
 \rowcolor{gray!50}\textbf{Class} & \makecell{Max Power\\ (mW)} & \makecell{Typ. Range\\(m)}\\
 \hline
 \textbf{1} & 100 & 100\\
 \textbf{2} & 2.5 & 10\\
 \textbf{3} & 1 & 1\\
 \textbf{4} & 0.5 & 0.5\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison between 2.4GHz and 5GHz}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
*Edit*:
For the spacing problem, I suggest to delete the modification of `\arraystretch`, to load the `cellspace` package and add these lines at the beginning of the table code (if you also load `siunitx` replace the letter `S` with the letter `C`):

```
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|Sc|Sc|}
```

Comment: what is the difference between 'makecell' and 'thead' commands? I can see that in your suggestion, there is no space around the 2-row cells. Can this be fixed? P.S. Apologies for the greek text, I forgot to change it.

Comment: There's no difference really, but you can specify their formatting independently. Semantically, `\thead` should be used for column heads, but it  resulted in a slightly longer code if yout to have the same font size as the rest of the table (the default font size is `\footnotesize`

Comment: @NickG: For the spacing problem, please see my edit.