# How can I remove the white lines in a colored multirow cell?

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a similar problem as in [Remove white line in painted multirow tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569359/remove-white-line-in-painted-multirow-tabula). Some PDF viewers like Adobe Reader and Evince display white lines inside my multirow cell.

thead/makecell doesn't work because I need to place the "Big Cell" at that exact position next to the three rows on the right. nicematrix sounds like a good solution, but unfortunately it's not available on my system (texlive2019).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

\newcommand{\cellgrey}[1]{\cellcolor{gray!40}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |*{5}{Y|} }
    
    \hhline{|-|-|-|-|-|}
    
    \cellgrey{} & \cellgrey{1} & \cellgrey{2} & \cellgrey{3} & \cellgrey{4}\\
    \hhline{|*1{>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!40}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|*4{-|}}

    \cellgrey{} & \cellgrey{5} & \cellgrey{6} & \cellgrey{7} & \cellgrey{8}\\
    \hhline{|*1{>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!40}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|*4{-|}}
    
    \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellgrey{Big Cell}} & \cellgrey{9} & \cellgrey{10} & \cellgrey{11} & \cellgrey{12}\\
    \hhline{|-|-|-|-|-|}
    
\end{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Any chance you could upgrade to TeXLive2022? The reason I ask is that I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you're getting on my fully updated MacTeX2022 system.

Answer (score 1):

This white lines seems tO be pdf viewer artifact. I can reproduce them with ma recent MiKTeX and Sumatra pdf viewer. However, using `tabularray` package, they disappear (the same will happen if you will use `nicematrix` package for setting of your table):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines=1pt, vlines=1pt,
             colspec = {*{5}{X[c]}},
             rowsep  = 5pt,
             rows    = {bg=gray!40}
             }
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    Big Cell
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4     \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4     \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]