# Misplaced alignment tab character for macro + token in tabularray environment

Tags: macros, tabularray, token

For some reason there's a conflict if I try to use tabularray in combination with macro + token.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newtoks\mynames
\NewEnviron{Names}{
    \global\mynames=\expandafter{\BODY}
}

\newcommand{\Name}[2]
{%
    #1 & #2 \\
}

\newenvironment{NameList}{
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec = {XX}}
    First name & Surname \\
}{\end{tblr}}

\begin{Names}
    \Name{James}{McGil}
    \Name{Charles}{McGil}
\end{Names}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NameList}
        \the\mynames
%       James & McGil \\ % this works
%       Charles & McGil \\ % this works
    \end{NameList}

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

[image: errors]

This is how it should look like:

[image: desired result]

Comment: tblr just *doesn't support* that, as you've already discovered. Stick with `NewEnviron`.

Comment: tabularray parses the content of the tabular body and so don't like if if you hide it inside commands. There are imho some options like execute which expand macros first, check the documentation (or use a normal tabular).

Comment: @user202729 I've already tried it with NewEnviron (by placing the \BODY there instead). Same error messages

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is that an option for newenvironment? I wasn't able to find it. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: I meant check the documentation of tabularray, and the name of the option I had in mind is `evaluate`. (But I would use tabular normally).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hm, I've tried the sample code in the documentation, but it seems like the tabularray version from 2021 isn't supported (I'm on texlive2019). I'd use tabular normally as well, but it doesn't look good on Adobe Reader and other PDF viewers, see [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655652/how-can-i-remove-the-white-lines-in-a-colored-multirow-cell)