# Datatool and Tabularray: "Misplaced alignment tab character &."

Tags: datatool, tabularray

I'd like to use [`datatool`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to populate a `longtblr` table (defined by [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)) with data.

I expected this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
Key,Value
a1,a2
b1,b2
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
    \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\DTLforeach]{colspec = {cc}}
    
    \DTLforeach*{data}{
        \key=Key,
        \value=Value%
    }{
        \key &
        \value\\
    }
    
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

to yield a table like:

[image: Table with "a1" and "a2" in the first row, "b1" and "b2" in the second]

but I receive the error:

```txt
27: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

Line `27` refers to: `\end{longtblr}`.

I added `[evaluate=\DTLforeach]` on a hunch based on the comments on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655706/211394). Deleting all the whitespace within `longtblr` has no effect.

## MWE Using `tabular`

This yields the expected result:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
Key,Value
a1,a2
b1,b2
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
    \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}

    \DTLforeach*{data}{
        \key=Key,
        \value=Value%
    }{
        \key &
        \value\\
    }
    
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

## MWE Using `xltabular`

As does this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
Key,Value
a1,a2
b1,b2
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
    \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{cc}
    
    \DTLforeach*{data}{
        \key=Key,
        \value=Value%
    }{
        \key &
        \value\\
    }
    
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

But I'd like to make use of `tabularray`'s rich feature set.

Comment: Essentially tabularray need to "see" the `&`s in the table content directly. You can use expl3 to construct the code to be executed, then execute all of it in one go.

Comment: That question implements the comment of @user202729, with an append-style construct `\edef\tblrbody{\tblrbody ... current row ...}` within `\DTLforeach`. That question does not use a csv but I am fairly sure it is applicable.

Comment: Thank you both. I was hoping to avoid `expl3` because it's wholly unfamiliar, but maybe it's time to learn. It will take me some time to fully understand that answer @Marjin, but it certainly looks applicable.