# Table border print perfectly but display inconsistent in AdobeReader

Tags: tables

I don't know if this is a known issue, I made table with {longtable} which print out perfectly, however when viewing in TexStudio or AdobeReader the border can be missing at some zoom level. The vertical border tends to be affected most.

Most people don't print nowadays, they read on a computer so the missing borders is like I don't pay attention to detail.

This is an example, the border around the colour boxes are missing:

```
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.42\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.11\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.11\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.11\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.11\textwidth}|}
    \caption{Vulnerability Summary}\\
    \hline 
    \textbf{Tested Infrastructure} & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00}\textbf{Low} & \cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}\textbf{Moderate} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFC702}\textbf{Important} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}\textbf{Critical} \\
    \hline \endfirsthead
    \hline \endhead
    UAT & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3          \\ 
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

I actually do a test to confirm, the original document table is inconsistent, I print the document to pdf, the printed pdf display better than the original document produced by TexStudio.

Comment: Yes this is known, you can find quite a number of question about this. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490663/solution-for-disappearing-table-cell-borders-with-rowcolor-in-the-pdf-viewer-de

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or even the colortbl package documentation.